# Reuse images from auction website

Tags: copyright, licensing, european-union

I bought a broken engine from an auction website. I fixed the engine and am now trying to resell it on the same auction website. The previous owner created some great images from the engine including all the details and serial numbers. I would like to reuse the same images to create my own listing. The ToS of the website state that the ownership of the images gets transferred to the auction website, which makes sense since they might use those images for a sponsored link/e-mail or other promotions.

If I now use those images for my listing, I am using images that are owned by the auction site and transfer ownership to the auction site. Is this correct? Or do I run into copyright issues?

Comment: Regarding the person downvoting the question, is something missing or wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You don’t own the copyright

So you can’t reproduce the images *or* transfer ownership of them. If you use them on the website you will be breaking the terms of service by purporting to do something (transfer ownership of the copyright) that you cannot do.

Take your own photos.

Comment: Regarding your last statment: I did. However, I am wondering, am I really transferring ownership of anything? I am using pictures that are already owned by the website I am submitting them to. So I am not reproducing them and not really transferring ownership of them.

Comment: You don’t own the images- you can’t copy them even to put them on a different part of the owner’s web site